How can I create an order that includes a trailing stop and 2 take profits?
I have a strategy that includes a trailing stop, and 2 take profits. the trailing stop should close the entire position, and the first take profit should be a partial close (obviously).
 if entryDirection == -1
        strategy.entry("Buy", strategy.long, 3)
        strategy.exit("Trailing Stop",  from_entry = "Buy", qty=3, trail_offset =4, trail_points = 0)
        strategy.exit("Exit Long ", from_entry = "Buy", qty = 2, profit = 4)
        strategy.exit("Exit Long 2", from_entry = "Buy", qty = 1, profit = 6) 

This is my order. The problem is that it seems to depend on what comes first in the order stack. if the TS is first, it will execute but neither of the TPs will. If the 2 TPs are above the TS, they will both execute but the TS will not. I can not figure out how to make them all work.
